# jqGrid Treegrid does not expand and collapse rows after dynamic load of data

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have a large bill of materials (BOM) that I have loaded into a jqGrid Treegrid. It has about 500 lines. For various reasons I am trying to keep the data chunks under 64K, so on larger BOMs I am not loading the deepest leaves, for example anything deeper than level 6. I want to dynamically load those when the user selects to expand a node that initially starts out collapsed because it was not loaded. Most everything works as expected. the user can collapse and expand any of the nodes that have been loaded. But, when the user clicks to expand a node with missing children, the server returns all of it's children, and it displays properly in the treegrid. If any of those children have collapsed nodes, the user can expand those an so on to the end of the branch. But that is where the normal behavior stops. Once the user clicks to expand any node with missing children, only the nodes that are included in the most recent server response can be expanded. Nothing can be collapsed. The error that is reported is:

```
An unexpected error has occurred: 
 'Unable to get property 'isleaf' of undefined or null reference'
 The url is ''
 The line number is 92
```

The source file that the line number refers to is grid.treegrid.js

Here is an example response for expanding a small node with missing children.

```
{"page":"1", 
 "total":"1", 
 "records":"3", 
 "rows":[
     {"id":"491","hide":false,"cell":["491","M-065934-1","BRACKET","M","1","1",".00","","&#036;.00","478","7","false","false"]},
     {"id":"492","hide":false,"cell":["492","M-065934-2","COLLAR","M","1","1",".00","","&#036;.00","478","7","false","true"]},
     {"id":"493","hide":false,"cell":["493","PD M6 X 20","PIN,DOWEL","P","2","2",".00","","&#036;.00","478","7","false","true"]}
 ]}
```

The last four values in each row are parent, level, expanded, and isleaf. In this case only row 491 is expandable once the data is loaded, and none of the rows surrounding these three rows, including the parent 478 are collapsible. What do I need to look at to determine the issue? Does loaded have any affect? I am not manually setting loaded on any row. I know which rows have unloaded children when I load the grid. Do I need to manually set that value?

jqGrid (free): 4.4.3
jQuery: 1.9.0
jQuery UI: 1.8.23

**Edit:** I have upgraded to the following releases:
jqGrid (free): 4.11.1
jQuery: 1.12.4
jQuery UI: 1.10.4

Beyond those versions I run into a problem with require.js which is being loaded, but doesn't seem to play nice with my configuration. I am getting the same errors (though the line number is different) here is the error now:

```
An unexpected error has occurred: 
 'Unable to get property 'expanded' of undefined or null reference'
 The url is 'http://as400/rui/scripts/jqgrid-4.11.1/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js?v=5.15b'
 The line number is 554
```

The root of the problem remains the same. While the treegrid data remains visible in the grid, it appears to be invisible to the jqgrid script. the properties of the rows that were there before the load are inaccessible, but the rows that were loaded during the update are indeed available, expandable (once), and are in the correct place in the grid.

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). The line 92 in `grid.treegrid.js` has different content in different versions of jqGrid. Moreover the data, which you posted, should correspond to the JavaScript code, which you should include too. I recommend you to try to load free jqGrid 4.13.4 from [CDN](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs) and repeat your tests.

Comment: Is there something majic about 4.13.4? I downloaded 4.13.5 from github, but it didn't work. The software I am using is an open source framework that included jqGrid. I guess it is quite old.

Comment: 1) the version 4.4.3 is too old and it's out of any support since a long time. 2) I made changed the code of TreeGrid in free jqGrid fork to improve it performance. You wrote that you loads many nodes in the TreeGrid. Thus it could be helpful for you. 3) if your code not work then you should create the demo, which uses non-minifed jqGrid (`jquery.jqgrid.src.js`) and which  reproduces the problem. Alternatively you should post at least JavaScript code, which create jqGrid.

Comment: I am going to try to get jQuery and jqGrid upgraded in my project. I will probably have questions.

Comment: I upgraded as far as I can right now. to go further, I am going to have to work out the appropriate dependencies for require.js Does this get you any closer to being able to help me?

Comment: Look at [the page](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html), which uses RequireJs with free jqGrid. Non-minimized version of the page is [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/free-jqgrid.github.io/tree/master/getting-started). One can comment `"free-jqgrid"` part of `define` and uncomment `"free-jqgrid-js-min/grid.custom"` line. The file `index.html` should contents of cause the reference of modified `data-main="require.config"` instead of `data-main="require.config.min"` used originally.

Comment: One can add `link rel="preload" as="script" href="...">` for all modules to improve a little the performance of loading in Chrome. In general it's the standard way of loading modules with RequireJs. I published **minimized modules** (with map and non-minimized files) on both free CDNs ([cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/free-jqgrid) and [jsdelivr](http://www.jsdelivr.com/projects/free-jqgrid)), which supports HTTP2. Thus the loading of separate modules works quickly and the files will be good cached in web browsers. *You should of cause use the latest 4.13.4 version instead of jqgrid-4.11.1.*

Comment: @Oleg I found the answer. I wrote it as an answer below. Maybe it is a bug. I was unable to upgrade at all because too much was different. So I am still using jqGrid 4.4.3. It is now working for me. This potential bug does exist in 4.11.1. The examples on http://www.guriddo.net/demo/treegridjs/ do show `loadonce: false` for the load rows on demand example, but I missed that one instance.

Comment: `loadonce:true` should not be used in TreeGrid because TreeGrid works *always* in the mode in case of usage `loadonce:true` (it saves the nodes/leafs locally in the internal `data` parameter). If you have interest in *unloading* previously loaded nodes then you can use new `unloadNodeOnCollapse` option, which I implemented in jqGrid 4.13.5. `unloadNodeOnCollapse` option can be either boolean or callback function. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/LocalAdjacencyTreeLoadOnDemand.htm), which unloads all nodes on collapsing if `level` > 0 (non top-level).

Comment: I used `loadonce:true` because all of the examples (except one that I missed) on http://www.guriddo.net/demo/treegridjs/ use `loadonce:true`. And in fact, if there are no dynamic rows in the grid, then `loadonce:true` works great. However, I will be using `loadonce:false` in the future.

Comment: I see that, but it's either bug in the demo or a new feature, implemented in Guriddo. I'm sure that the usage of `loadonce:true` is wrong (or has no effects) in all version of jqGrid till 4.7 (inclusive 4.4.3). In any way I recommend you to try the performance of you application in case of usage 4.13.5 with `unloadNodeOnCollapse` option. If you would have some compatibility problems, you can send new question with the coresponding demo, which uses non-minimized version of jqGrid and which reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it took a lot of debugging, but I found the answer. The secret sauce lies in the `loadonce` property of the treegrid. This property must have a value of `false` in order to allow the treegrid to dynamically load additional nodes. This goes hand in hand with the isleaf property of the row. I found that if the treegrid has `loadonce: true`, and any rows have `isleaf: false` and the child nodes are not loaded, then when you expand that child node, all of the local data is deleted and replaced by the child row data, but the grid itself is manipulated properly and becomes out of sync with the local data. `loadonce: false` suppresses deletion of the local data, and the local data and grid remain in sync.

Maybe this is a bug. If you have `loadonce: true`, maybe treegrid should suppress posting for additional nodes. Rather than making the grid and local data out of sync.

BTW, I am using the adjacency model for this.

Comment: I recommend you to examine the grid with respect of Developer Tools of web browser after collapsing the node. If the nodes are removed then you should don't see any hidden rows with old nodes (you should see no `<tr role="row" id="someid" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" style="display: none;">` elements). By usage `unloadNodeOnCollapse: false` in free jqGrid 4.13.5 you can force the behavior. Any data about children will be deleted from both internal `data` parameter and from DOM of the grid.

Comment: That is how I found it. In Chrome developer tools, by debugging the script. The local data is cleared, and replaced with the child rows when `loadonce: true` is set, and an unloaded node is expanded. This happens in function `addJSONData` in `grid.base.js`. This is the code that does it `locdata = (ts.p.datatype != "local" && ts.p.loadonce) || ts.p.datatype == "jsonstring"; if(locdata) { ts.p.data = []; ts.p._index = {}; ts.p.localReader.id = locid;}`. Later, the rows are added to the grid in the DOM. This leaves the grid and the local data out of sync.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure about which version of jqGrid you wrote in your last comment. I repeat that the usage of `loadonce: true` is wrong in all versions of jqGrid: some versions can ignore the option, but some can have side effects. TreeGrid fills `data` always in case of usage TreeGrid and one can inform jqGrid that full data are already loaded only by usage `loaded` property of the server response. Thus the option `loadonce: true` has absolutely no sense in case of usage TreeGrid.

Comment: I am using 4.4.3 because that is what is in the framework I am using, and I am unable to upgrade. Not because of any issue with jqGrid, but because I am not that knowledgeable of javascript. Anyway, this should be pointed out on the free jqGrid wiki page because all but one of the examples on http://www.guriddo.net/demo/treegridjs/ are wrong, and there is no indication that what you are saying is the case. I believe you, and I will be using `loadonce:false` in the future.

Comment: `loadonce:false` is just default value. It's better just don't use `loadonce` at all in case of usage TreeGrid.